# When retrieving data in vb.net from AS400 table ,column value(for a varchar column) is returned as byte array instead of string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ibm-midrange

I have a VB.NET web application where i am retrieving the data from AS400 .Two of the columns EXT_CLR_DESC,INT_CLR_DESC are varchar in the table and i was running the application successfully for months getting strings for both the columns.But now the columns are being returned as Byte array and i didnt change any code in the .NET application .When i ran the  Query on AS400 i am still getting data correctly as varchar .But when i try to access it through web application it returns byte array

This is my below code in VB.NET

```
Public Function FetchIntExtColor(ByVal psFranchise As String, ByVal psModelCode As String, ByVal psCharCode As String, ByRef pdtIntExtColor As DataTable, ByRef psErr As String) As Boolean
      Dim lsSql As String
      Dim lcmdEnquiry As IDbCommand = Nothing
      Try

        lsSql = "SELECT EXT_CLR_CODE,INT_CLR_CODE,EXT_CLR_DESC,INT_CLR_DESC FROM " & csSchema.Trim & "vhvvmdl01 WHERE FRAN_CODE Like '%' "

        If psFranchise.Trim <> "" Then
          lsSql = lsSql & " And FRAN_CODE = ?"
        End If
        If psModelCode.Trim <> "" Then
          lsSql = lsSql & " And MODEL_CODE = ?"
        End If
        If psCharCode.Trim <> "" Then
          lsSql = lsSql & " And CHAR_CODE = ?"
        End If

        lcmdEnquiry = coNonTransactional.GetCommand(lsSql)
        lcmdEnquiry.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        If psFranchise.Trim <> "" Then
          AddStringParam2Command("@FRAN_CODE", psFranchise.Trim, lcmdEnquiry)
        End If

        If psModelCode.Trim <> "" Then
          AddStringParam2Command("@MODEL_CODE", psModelCode.Trim, lcmdEnquiry)
        End If

        If psCharCode.Trim <> "" Then
          AddStringParam2Command("@CHAR_CODE", psCharCode.Trim, lcmdEnquiry)
        End If
        pdtIntExtColor = coNonTransactional.ExecuteDataAdapterDataTableWithParams(lcmdEnquiry)
        FetchIntExtColor = True
      Catch ex As Exception
        psErr = ex.Message
        FetchIntExtColor = False
      Finally
        lcmdEnquiry.Dispose()
        lcmdEnquiry = Nothing
      End Try
    End Function
```

This is the Query i got from the web application which runs successfully on AS400

```
SELECT EXT_CLR_CODE,INT_CLR_CODE,EXT_CLR_DESC,INT_CLR_DESC FROM TABLE WHERE FRAN_CODE Like '%'  And FRAN_CODE = 'A' And MODEL_CODE = 'TGN141' And CHAR_CODE = 'HC'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the columns returning byte array instead of string was that COALESCE was used on both of the columns in the view definition from which i was retrieving data. .Once i removed COALESCE from the view the issue was gone.